# Coredata groupby properties iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I want to implement an `SQL` query in `iOS` `CoreData`, here's my query.

```
Select * from table group by my_field1 order by my_field2
```

I want to show the `GroupBy` of the attribute `my_field1` but I'm getting error that default value can't be nil.

Here's my code:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"myentity"];
[fetchRequest setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
fetchRequest.propertiesToGroupBy = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"my_field1"];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"my_field2" ascending:YES];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];

  NSMutableArray *data = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];
```

How can I filter the results by Group by properties in Coredata.

My desire results are:

My Table Data:

```
my_field1      |      my_field2     |     my_field3

1                     ABC                 DEF
1                     GHI                 JKL
1                     MNO                 PQR
2                     DEF                 DEF
```

My Expected results:

```
 my_field1      |      my_field2     |     my_field3

1                      MNO                 PQR
2                      DEF                 DEF
```

Im expecting the last row found for `my_field1` as im also inluding order_by in query.

Comment: Do you want to obtain the *values* "1", "MNO" and "PQR" (and "2", "DEF" and "DEF"), or do you want the *NSManagedObjects* that have those values?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the other fields you are selecting to the `propertiesToGroupBy` array.  Otherwise, how does it know what to do with those other fields?  For example, say you had the following data:

```
   my_field_1     my_field_2

      John          Smith

      John          Jones
```

If you were to group by just my_field_1 then it would result in:

```
    my_field_1     my_field_2

      John          ??????
```

In this example, you need to either group by my_field_2 as well or apply some aggregate function.

In your example, you are selecting all fields in the table, so there are potentially many fields that need to be grouped, aggregated with a count/sum/etc, or left out by adding them to `fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch =` and only including the desired properties.

### Edit

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"myentity" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
NSDictionary *propertiesByName = [entity propertiesByName];
fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = @[[propertiesByName objectForKey:@"my_field_2"],[propertiesByName objectForKey:@"my_field_3", [propertiesByName objectForKey:@"my_field_4"]];
```

Comment: OK, so how can I select `my_field3, my_field4, my_field5` when Im running this query, `Select my_field3, my_field4, my_field5 from table group by my_field1`

Comment: The edit was just addressing your comment... how do you select.  As I say in my OP, anything you want to group by you need to select.  Anything you select though needs to be in the group by as well or have an aggregate function applied to it.  Otherwise, your query doesn't make sense.

Comment: Then your question then needs to be more clear. Please include sample data of what you would like to query, and what you expect the output to be.

Comment: Based on your edit, why do you need a group by?  It seems that you just want to select entities where @"my_field_2"  is equal to the strings @"MNO" or @"DEF"?

Comment: NO no I want to pick the last row that is why i added in my sql query, order by my_field3 desc